# When do campaign signs go up for US Presidential Elections?

Tags: usa, road-trips

I am planning a six-month road trip throughout the USA, and I have a pretty broad timeline for when it could start, but I’m hoping to go sometime within the next couple years. I want to film the drive with a dash cam, and make a video/website/art project from the footage. Just today it occurred to me that there is an election in the states next year, and that the roadsides being full of trump/democrat signs would really deteriorate the quality of that project.

So when do signs usually go up? How many are there, particularly on long interstate highways?

Comment: There won't be many on interstate highways.

Comment: Great. It’ll be a lot of driving between national parks, so I think that’s lots of interstates, a few scenic byways, and then the roads into the small towns near the parks. Election signs not a big worry?

Comment: It depends a bit where you are. Yard signs will be in people's yards, so you won't really see them on interstate highways, but you might find some billboards near highways, and some of those may have political ads. That said, the signs aren't obtrusive, just a fairly small sign some people will have in their yard.

Comment: @liam it's any roads you please. You're perfectly welcome to snub the Interstates and drive the US or State highways.  The latter will be more likely to have political signs, but less likely to have unsightly billboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I live, they're already up in people's yards. Then again I live in New Hampshire, where the first presidential primary happens in January 2020. They'll mostly go away after that and be replaced with signs for whoever ends up winning in each party.

A few people have never taken down the Trump signs from their yards.

If you're filming major highways, you aren't likely to see many such signs though. Those won't start showing up on billboards in any significant quantity until the end of 2019 and into 2020, depending on the state. Virtually none of these will remain up long past election day.

Overall I'd say that if you don't want such signs in your video, there probably isn't all that much you can do. You're going to see one in the US eventually regardless of when you come. As a general rule I'd say the time to see the least amount of election signs is from a few months after a presidential election to the following year. In the second year, signs will start coming up for Congressional races...

You might be able to learn how to remove them from your video with a video editing tool, the way they [removed the coffee cup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7ZvF_sF1eA) from Game of Thrones.

From your requirements I'd say the best time overall to avoid election signs of any sort, and have good driving conditions all over the country, would be spring through autumn of 2020.

Comment: I think perhaps the OP was thinking about campaign posters hanging from streetlight masts etc on major roads as it is tradition in some countries, e.g. Denmark, [as in this image](https://videnskab.dk/sites/default/files/styles/columns_12_12_desktop/public/article_media/ok_valgplakater.jpg) or [this](https://www.tv2lorry.dk/files/styles/16_9_medium_2x/public/media/2017/44/valgplakater.jpg). I gather from the replies here that this does not happen in the US at all?

Comment: Holy carp! Those poor trees! No, placing them on trees doesn't really happen that much. Normally they're placed on metal stakes in the ground, something like [this](https://images1.dallasobserver.com/imager/u/745xauto/11654631/campaignsigns.jpg). These are mostly in private yards on city streets, though, not on highways. People also hold up signs near polling places on election day.

Comment: That said, I have seen very large signs on private property adjacent to highways, generally also staked into the ground. Occasionally people hang signs off bridges, but as that's usually illegal they get taken down pretty quickly.

Comment: In the last few elections, I haven't noticed highway billboards being used for campaign ads much at all.  Maybe campaigns just don't think they're the best way to spend their advertising dollars.  But as you say, sometimes property owners adjacent to a highway will display large signs on their grounds or buildings.

Comment: @NateEldredge I saw quite a few of them in 2016, but again I live in New Hampshire, and we have to deal with this for nearly two years out of every four.